# Config Axios globally with Authenticated in NuxtJS - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I finding way to config Axios globally with Authenticated in NuxtJS - VueJS (I use mainly NUXTJS).

All I need is: *If user logged in and have token in $store, axios will get this token. If user is anonymous, axios wont get this token*

**~/plugins/axios**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import AuthenticationStore from '~/store'

var api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/',
  'headers': {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + AuthenticationStore.state.token}
})

api.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  config.headers = {
    'Authorization': AuthenticationStore.state.token ? 'JWT ' + AuthenticationStore.state.token : ''
  }
  return config
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error)
})

export default api
```

**~/store/index.js**

```
const AuthenticationStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      token: null
    },
    mutations: {
      SET_TOKEN: function (state, token) {
        state.token = token
        instance.defaults.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
      }
    },
    actions: {
      ....
    }
  })
}

export default AuthenticationStore
```

Error: `[nuxt] Error while initializing app TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`

Comment: Did you try exporting the state as a function like:
export const state = () => ({
  // goes here
})

Comment: I tried it like you said in `~/store/index.js`. Take a look my code above please!

Comment: Well, I just wondered if you tried the modules approach way shown [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#classic-mode), but apparently it is more like the classical way. Then, I can say using the state like `this.$state.token` might help.

Comment: @vahdet Thanks. I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use interceptor instead which is more flexible and getting token when making request not on creation. Try something like that to avoid issues with not set token.

```
// ~/plugins/axios
import axios from 'axios'
import AuthenticationStore from '~/store'

var api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/',
  'headers': {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + AuthenticationStore.state.token}
})
 api.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  config.headers = {
    'Authorization': AuthenticationStore.state.token ? 'Bearer ' + AuthenticationStore.state.token : ''
  }
  return config
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
export default api
```

If you need to have no auth header, you need to add if at the begging of the interceptor.

**Issue with your store:**
You are exporting function when you should export instance of store,
so this is wrong:

```
const AuthenticationStore = () => {
```

You should export instance so:

```
const AuthenticationStore = new Vuex.Store({ ...
```

Please visit https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/ to get better understanding. It is not bad that you don't understand it fully! Modules/instances/exporting in JS is not really easy to understand fully. Just try to learn it more. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake about code in `store/index.js`. Please review my code above. I have some issues about import store into axios.js file.

Comment: what issues exactly you have?

Comment: My error is `[nuxt] Error while initializing app TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`

Comment: When I console.log(AuthenticationStore), it render: `AuthenticationStore() {
  return new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7_vuex__["default"].Store({
    state: {
      authUser: null,
      userInfo: null,
      token: null
    },`

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Youre right. I just understand vaguely about Vuex Store. Maybe I'll try it. Thanks for help :)